# In the original GAN paper, why is it mentioned that you can sample deep directed graphical models without a Markov chain?

Tags: bayesian-networks, markov-chain, probabilistic-graphical-models

In the original [GAN paper (table 2)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2014/file/5ca3e9b122f61f8f06494c97b1afccf3-Paper.pdf#page=8), why is it mentioned that you can sample deep directed graphical models without a Markov chain (well, they say without difficulties, but others list MCMC as a difficulty).

I was wondering how this is done because I have only seen MCMC based approaches.

[image]